# javascript webkitTransform style attributes not setting - scope?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, scope, webkit

I'm trying to set the webkitTransform style attribute, but it's not setting for some reason. But there are other attributes that are successfully being set to the div.

This doesn't work:

```
var cell = document.createElement("div");
var canvas = document.createElement("img");

cell.className = "baz";
cell.appendChild(canvas);

cell.style.color = "bar";

cell.style.webkitTransform = "foo"; 

alert(cell.style.webkitTransform);  //doesn't work - returns empty  
alert(cell.style.color);            //doesn't work - returns empty
alert(cell.className);              //outputs "baz" -- works as expected
```

This is all nested inside a somewhat complex set of functions, where the consequences of scope aren't totally clear to me, but that doesn't seem to me to have anything to do with this...

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting an actual transform on the div? Like cell.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(45deg)";

Comment: that code is just the test for when I try to set it to a real attribute... and it doesnt work.

but since you're really just setting the text value of these attributes, it shouldnt matter what the values are, right?

Comment: spoke too soon. I had a malformed style attribute. once I put in a valid one it worked.